# Recycle IIS Application Pool: Cannot connect to SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I have sample webpart application and want to change my SharePoint site url in the existing code before deploying. It shows following error.

```
Recycle IIS Application Pool: Cannot connect to SharePoint site: http://abc/
```

I know htt://abc is not available on my SharePoint form. how can i change that url in my existing sample code/webpart SharePoint project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight your SharePoint project in Solution Explorer and open the Properties window you should see a field named "Site URL" that you can modify to the correct URL.